# How to write a trigger to update an attribute in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have the following relations:

```
Restaurant(rname, address, phone, stars)

Chef(cname, specialdish, rating)

CooksFor(cname, rname, salary)
```

I am tasked with writing a trigger to increase the `salary` of each chef by 10% when the restaurant they cook for receives an increase in the number of stars it has.

Here is what I've written, based on my notes from class and some examples I found online:

```
CREATE TRIGGER salary_increase BEFORE UPDATE ON Restaurant
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.stars > stars
        THEN UPDATE Chef
            SET salary = 1.1*salary
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT C.cname FROM Chef C, CooksFor CF
                         WHERE C.cname = CF.cname AND
                         CF.rname = Restaurant.rname)
        END IF
    END
```

Would this work? Is there a better/more correct way of doing it?

I tried to find an example online of a similar problem but found that most people only needed to reference one other table. Since the only way I can find which chefs cook for which restaurant is by using the CooksFor table, I got a bit confused when trying to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Can a chef cook for more than 1 restaurant?

Comment: @P.Salmon We're not told explicitly whether or not its possible. I assumed so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for the trigger seems sound, I would consider using `INNER JOIN` for your `UPDATE`:

```
    UPDATE C
    SET C.salary = 1.1*C.salary
    FROM Chef C   
    INNER JOIN CooksFor CF
    ON CF.cname = C.cname
    AND CF.rname = NEW.rname
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question though, with the line `UPDATE C`, does `C` not have to be "declared" there? Or is that done in the `FROM` statement?

Comment: @SSmrao Yeah the `C` is an alias for `Chef` table and it comes as you have pointed from the `FROM` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much!